# Classic asp . Objects not shown

Tags: html, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a weird issue. I have a website built with classic asp. It was working fine for years, but now for some reason, some of my htc are not shown when the page loads. Then when I try to access these objects like this: document.All(objName).value, I get: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `document.All.objName.value` if `objName` is an actual element ID (not a variable), or `document.getElementById(objName)` if it's a variable with an element ID.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using IExplorer 9

Answer (score 1):

First of all wanted to mention this got nothing to do with classic ASP, it's pure client side issue.

Now to the point. The notorious `document.all` should not be used, period. Client side VBScript should also be avoided becuase it's IE only meaning it won't work for over 50% of your visitors.

To sum it up: switch to JavaScript and use the standard `document.getElementById`. Change your code from such line:

```
MyValue = document.All(objName).value
```

To this instead:

```
var myValue = document.getElementById(objName).value;
```

In case the *objName* is name and not id e.g. `<input type="text" name="MyInput" />` you can use:

```
var myValue = document.getElementsByName("MyInput")[0].value;
```

(assuming you have only one element with that name)

Answer (score 0):

Was it solved? If this issue was particularly generated on IE browser, you could make it compatible version by adding the following line of ASP code?

Response.AddHeader "X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge,chrome=1"